# Password protected zip file using Python

Tags: python, subprocess, zip, password-protection

I'm trying to password protect zip files that I'm creating in a python script but have not been able to figure out why when I try to unzip it does not accept the password that the script created.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
import subprocess, random, os

file = "test.csv"
s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!@#$%^&*()?"
zipPass = "".join(random.sample(s,12))
print zipPass
devnull = open(os.devnull, 'w')
rc = subprocess.call("zip -P "+str(zipPass)+" "+str(file)+".zip "+str(file), shell=True, stdout=devnull, stderr=devnull)
```

When I run the script and try to unzip I get the following;

```
user@server:/tmp/zip> zip.py
xxxxxxxxx
user@server:/tmp/zip> unzip test.csv.zip
Archive:  test.csv.zip
[test.csv.zip] test.csv password:
password incorrect--reenter:
```

I've tried copying/pasting the password and also manually entering just to be sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: Your `subprocess.call` invocation would be much simpler if you dropped `shell=True` and passed a list instead of a string. You might even find that it solves your problem. You also seem to have some unnecessary calls to `str()` there that you could leave out.

Comment: The calls to str() were a result of me losing my mind while trying to debug what was going on.  They'll be removed :)  I'll definitely look into using a list instead as it'd be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Tested your script worked for me. just to be sure , remove created zip file run script and check if it is zip file which created by your script. I said this because you didn't define path to store zip file, so it is possible your file is created somewhere else and you are looking to wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I figured it out a little earlier this morning.  The version of zip I'm running does not like special characters !@#$%^&*()? in the password.  I discovered this when a password worked on one of the zips that only used [a-Z0-9].  When the password contained any of those special characters zip creation failed.

Comment: Great, glad to hear that.